# Config DustJS (ServerSide) do not escape new line?

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

I'm using DustJS with ExpressJS with NodeJS.

When ExpressJS renders, it auto escape the new line and white space in my dustJS; while since I'm putting JavaScript into my DustJS templates, I want to leave the white spaces as it is.

How to achieve that?

Thanks a lot.

Update: here's some further explanation:

In my template.dust, I have something like:

```
 <script type='template' id="tempVO">{.vo|s}</script>
 <script>  {! Block to compile the dustJS into cache !}
 $(function($){
   dust.compile($("#tempVO").html(),"vo");

   // register helper
   dust.helpers.justToString = function(chunk, ctx, body, param){
     console.log(param);
   }
 })();
```

The default behaviour of DustJS, when used with expressJS by doing:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.render("ajaxTemplate",xmlService.templates);
});
```

would escape all the white spaces so that it turns out something like:

```
 $(function($){dust.compile($("#tempVO").html(),"vo");// register helperdust.helpers.justToString = function(chunk, ctx, body, param){console.log(param);}})();// AJAX Callback</script><script>$(function(){$(".tipNeeded").tooltip();$(".tabsNeeded").tabs();});
```

Which is certainly not what I want.]

Although I can just use some external JavaScript Import, like:

```
  <script src="my/own/beautiful.js"></script>
```

Still I'd like to know how to put in-HTML script by not-escaping the white space when render my dustJS files.

Comment: Please explain a bit more clearly what you want, with some code

Comment: @user1737909 thanks for reply. Detailed code updated.

Comment: express doesn't clear whitespace for me. Maybe you can configure dust or use /* */ comments instead

Comment: @user1737909 Hi thx for reply.. This doesn't really solves the problem though.. BTW I did another google search and I got this: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/238

Answer (score 1):

From the [Dust Tutorial](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial) on [controlling whitespace suppression](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Controlling_whitespace_suppression), the exact method would vary based upon the version you are using.  If you are on v1.2.6 (the latest as of this writing) you would add this line to your code:

`dust.optimizers.format = function(ctx, node) { return node };`

To quickly test it, add that line immediately after your require for the dustjs-linkedin module:

`var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');`

**Edit:**

From version 1.2.0 to 1.2.5, the compile function took three arguments:

`dust.compile = function(source, name, strip)`

If `strip` was set to `false` then whitespace would be preserved.  However, it looks like this argument was [removed in 1.2.6](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/pull/278). Even with a version that has the `strip` argument, when using [express](http://expressjs.com), you aren't calling `dust.compile` directly.  You might be able to use something like [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/) as a basis to write two render calls, one with whitespace and one without...but I don't see a plainly simple way.

Comment: Hi thx for reply. Is it possible to.. like.. just suppress whitespace for certain views only?